# Attachments to multiple email

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I am trying to send emails to multiple recipients with respective pdf files attached.

I was successful with sending emails to multiple recipients but the attachment sent to the recipients were all the same file. The scenario should be like this: recipient A should have email attached with pdf A, recipient B with pdf B, so on and so fort.

Those pdf's have file names that correspond to the unique control number that each recipient has. E.g. recipient A has control number 1234, so his pdf is named as 1234.pdf.

I tried to do a wile loop in `$ctrl_no = mysql_result($ctrl, 0)` but it gives an error saying that the memory limit of the server has reached. I already tried raising up the memory limit but it didn't work.

Hope you could help solve.

```
$input = addslashes($_POST['dep']);                                                                                                     

$email = "select email_address  from student y where y.center = '$input'"; 


if ($p_address=mysql_query($email))
{ 

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($p_address))
 {     

 $mail->AddAddress($row[0]);

 $input = addslashes($_POST['dep']);                        


 $control = "select control_no  from student y where y.center = '$input'";

 if($ctrl=mysql_query($control)){

 $ctrl_no = mysql_result($ctrl, 0);


 $mail->AddAttachment("reports/".$ctrl_no.".pdf");  


 }
  else{

   echo "No attached pdf.";

  }
```

Comment: Function mysql_* are deprecated, try to use PDO:: take a look here http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an idea about PDO just to jump-start my coding?

Comment: Look man, if you are just going to stalk my posts, you are not helping at all. I suggest you help me figure this out and we are good to go.

Comment: I recomend you to check if the file is on server. Check if the patch is ok. To figure it with PDO you can do something like this $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass); foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {